# Saving Tensorflow model from Java

Tags: python, java, tensorflow, jvm, tensorflow2.0

How to use TensorFlow's SavedModelBundle.Exporter to export a model for use in Python.

I've created this test script:

```
    try(Graph graph = new Graph()) {
        Ops tf = Ops.create(graph);

        Operand x = tf.constant(1);
        Operand y = tf.placeholder(TInt32.class);

        Operand sum = tf.math.add(x, y);

        try(Session session = new Session(graph)){

            Signature signature = Signature.builder().input("Input1", y).output("Output1", sum).build();
            SessionFunction function = SessionFunction.create(signature, session);
            SavedModelBundle.exporter("C:\\TFModel")
                    .withSession(session)
                    .withFunction(function)
                    .export();

        }
    }

    System.out.println("Done");
```

This doesn't throw any errors when creating the model in java but when loading the model into Python it throws this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3939, in _as_graph_element_locked
    return op.outputs[out_n]
IndexError: list index out of range

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\tensorflowJava\Builder.py", line 7, in <module>
    tf.saved_model.load(
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\load.py", line 900, in load
    result = load_internal(export_dir, tags, options)["root"]
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\load.py", line 958, in load_internal
    root = load_v1_in_v2.load(export_dir, tags)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\load_v1_in_v2.py", line 286, in load
    result = loader.load(tags=tags)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\load_v1_in_v2.py", line 268, in load
    signature_functions = self._extract_signatures(wrapped, meta_graph_def)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\load_v1_in_v2.py", line 176, in _extract_signatures
    signature_fn = wrapped.prune(feeds=feeds, fetches=fetches)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\wrap_function.py", line 325, in prune
    fetches = nest.map_structure(_fetch_preprocessing_callback, fetches)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\nest.py", line 869, in map_structure
    structure[0], [func(*x) for x in entries],
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\nest.py", line 869, in <listcomp>
    structure[0], [func(*x) for x in entries],
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\wrap_function.py", line 311, in _fetch_preprocessing_callback
    decoded = _get_element_from_tensor_info(fetch, self._func_graph)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\wrap_function.py", line 104, in _get_element_from_tensor_info
    return graph.as_graph_element(tensor_info.name)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3895, in as_graph_element
    return self._as_graph_element_locked(obj, allow_tensor, allow_operation)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3941, in _as_graph_element_locked
    raise KeyError("The name %s refers to a Tensor which does not "
KeyError: "The name 'Init:0' refers to a Tensor which does not exist. The operation, 'Init', exists but only has 0 outputs."
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't get why you're training your model in Java then try to use in Python. Basically, Python is preferred for creating models, not java. Also loading and using model in Python is more easy. Check how to build model using keras and tensorflow [keras.io](https://keras.io/)